# Error 403: forbidden error

Tags: codeigniter

I can't access a controller using a form in Codeigniter 2.1. The homepage has several links and I can access. But when I want to submint data in a form I display the 403 forbidden error:

Forbidden you don't have permission to access /Pruebas/application/controllers/valiar.php on this server.

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Anuncios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pruebas/css/estilos.css" type="text/css"   
    media="screen"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pruebas/css/logestilos.css" type="text/css" 
    media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="contenedor">
<div id="menu">
    <label for="home" id="inicio"><a href="http://localhost/Pruebas/index.php 
            /cindice/">Inicio</a></label> 
    <label for="acceso" id="login"><a href="http://localhost/Pruebas/index.php
            /cindice/publicar">Publicar anuncio</a></label> 
    <label for="reg" id="registro"><a href="http://localhost/Pruebas/index.php
            /cindice/registro">Registro</a></label>
    <label for="empresa" id="sobrempresa"><a href="http://localhost/Pruebas
            /index.php/cindice/sobempresa">Sobre nosotros</a></label>
    <label for="contacto" id="contactar"><a href="http://localhost/Pruebas   
            /index.php/cindice/contacto">Cont&aacute;ctanos</a></label>
</div>  
</div>

<div id="acformulario"> 
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <form action="http://localhost/Pruebas/application/controllers   
            /validar.php" method="post">
    <label for="correo" id="dcorreo">Direcci&oacute;n de correo</label>
    <input type="text" name="drcorreo" id="dcc"/><br /><br />
    <label for="contrasenya" id="cont">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="cmcont"/><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="envia" id="bentrar" value="Entrar" />    
    </form>
 </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Cindice extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('indice');
}

    public function validar() 
{
    $this->input->post('drcorreo');
    $this->input->post('contrasena');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo','Direcci&oacute;n de  
            correo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenya','Contrase&ntilde;a',
            'trim|required|md5|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
     {
        echo ("validaci&oacute;n v&aacute;lida");   
     }
    else {
        $this->load->view('');
        echo ("validaci&oacute;n incorrecta");
         }  
}
```

My .htacess file has the words deny from all. How can I acess to the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action should look like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('validar'); // needs the form helper to be loaded ?>
```

... instead of:

```
<form action="http://localhost/Pruebas/application/controllers/validar.php" method="post">
```

You can't give the controller's file path as the location for the form action.

Comment: <?php echo form_open('cindice/validar') - Just to be safe.

Comment: His code's a bit unclear on that. He seems to have a `validar.php` controller, but then he also has a controller `cindice.php` with `validar` method. It'll depend on his setup - but yeah, good catch :)

Comment: Correct...but as per the supplied code excerpt above, the form should submit to cindice/validar. I reckon he is new to CI and is misusing the MVC pattern.

Comment: Thanks for answers. It works now. I changed the controller name by naming it valida instead of validar and I typed echo form_open("cindice/validar). But what I don't understand is why CodeIgniter doesn't show errors when I don't type anything in usuario or contrasenya field form. It would be displayed the rules that are in the form_validation_lang.php. I have the default language English.

Comment: @axmug please mark my answer as having solved your problem. Make a new post for the other problem you mention above, as it is not related to your initial question. Thx :)